# If $m$ is a multiple of $n$ then $\mathbb{Z}_{m}/{\mathbb{Z}_{n}} \cong \mathbb{Z_{\frac{m}{n}}}$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I got this problem from my group theory's lecture.

> If $m,n>1$ and $m$ is a multiple of $n$, then
>
> $$ {\mathbb{Z}_{m}}/{\mathbb{Z}_{n}} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{\frac{m}{n}} $$

My attempt:
Define a function $f:\mathbb{Z}_{m}\rightarrow{\mathbb{Z_{\frac{m}{n}}}}$  such that for every $z\in{\mathbb{Z}} \text{ } \text{ } f([z]_{m})=[z]_{\frac{m}{n}}$, and testing specific cases in $n$ and $m$ I've found that $Ker(f) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{n}$, to show this in the general case the problem is reduced to prove for every $n$ and $m$ multiple of n

$$ \{ a <m \text{  } | \text{ }  a|\frac{m}{n} \}$$

must have $n$ elements. But I can't find a way to prove this. Any hint?

Comment: Write the elements of $\mathbb Z_m$ as $kn+l$.

Comment: Your reduction doesn't work. For example, if $m = 24$, $n = 12$, it says that the set $\{ a < 24 \mid (a \mid 2)\}$ has 12 elements.

Comment: Just count the number of elements, and realise that both groups are cyclic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove that two groups are isomrphic, you need to give an isomorphism (an invertible homomorphism), your map is a good choice , but you need to verify that it is well defined (it does not depend on the representative of classe, i.e., $a\cong b[m]\implies a\cong b[\frac{m}{n}]$), then it is homomorphism ,surjective and that  $\ker(f)\cong \mathbb{Z}_{n}$,more specifically $\ker(f)=\langle[\frac{m}{n}]\rangle$ (one inclusion is trivial$\langle[\frac{m}{n}]\rangle\subset \ker(f)$ and u can prove the other direction using surjectivity by applying the first isomorphism theorem).

Comment: I don't get where using the first isomorphism theorem to prove the other inclusion, but I think I got it with if $x$ is in the $Ker(f)$ then $x$ is equal to $0$ modulo $m/n$, then $x=(\frac{m}{n})k$ implies that $x$ is in $<[\frac{m}{n}]>$. The rest was super clear, thank you so much:)

Comment: @AlexeyCortés by the first isomorphism theorem $\frac{m}{n}=\lvert Im(f)=\mathbb{Z}_{\frac{m}{n}}\rvert =\lvert I\mathbb{Z}_{m} /Ker(f) \rvert=\frac{m}{\lvert Ker(f)\rvert }$,so $\lvert Ker(f)\rvert =n$ but $<\lvert \frac{m}{n}\rvert=n>$,so they must be equal.